# A method of getting the value of fields without using reflection

Tags: java

I've been given a class with some 200 fields in which their values are read using reflection. It looks basically like this

```
for (Field f : this.getClass().getFields())
        {
            try
            {
                Object o = f.get(this);

                if (f.getType() == String.class)
                {
                    //do things with the string
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.error("Cannot get value for field. {}", ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

This works very well for such an unwieldy amount of fields as I suppose is the point of reflection. I've been asked to refactor it because it's slow (is it?).

So far the only method I can come up with his an ungodly amount of hard coding, is there another quick method?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has a working code and asks for a refactor. Please have a look at [ask] and consider asking this question on [codereview.se].

Comment: Better, put the whole class. "Slow" - it depends on a class usage and content. Personally, I think that reflection here is the best solution... if you want to save the same logic. Looks like this is an abstraction failure (mess with the 200 fields inside one class are needed to be processed and !filtered many times), not a serious realisation flaw.

Comment: Is it slow? You tell me. Put a profiler on your program and see how much time it spends in this loop.

Comment: If you can modify the class in question, you may be able to obtain something by putting the data into for instance an `ArrayList<String>` or a `HashMap<String, String>` instead of all those fields (or both if you still need the fields for compatibility, but you’d want to avoid redeudancy).

Answer (score 4):

First you should verify with a profiler that it indeed is slow. Reflection is slower than accessing variables normally, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's the source of slowness.

Provided that you're using setters to modify those values, you can refactor the class to update a `Map<String,Object>` whenever a setter is called. This provides faster access to the fields than reflection, but may not be possible depending on your use case.

Comment: Ah, very nice. Sadly the fields are public and are set directly.

Comment: @Nanor The one time setters would be of use...!

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time is spent in obtaining the Field objects (and possibly filtering them) The actual lookup can be pretty fast. I use ClassValue to cache this information and speed it up.

```
public enum StringFields {
    INSTANCE;

    final ClassValue<List<Field>> fieldsCache = new ClassValue<List<Field>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<Field> computeValue(Class<?> type) {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(
                    Stream.of(type.getFields())
                            .filter(f -> f.getType() == String.class)
                            .peek(f -> f.setAccessible(true)) // turn off security check
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    };

    public static List<Field> getAllStringFields(Class<?> type) {
        return INSTANCE.fieldsCache.get(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I knew the name of the fields I could do `Object.get(String)` and it would be faster?

Comment: @Nanor if you have the Field objects cached it would be faster. Will add an example but busy atm

Answer (score 1):

> So far the only method I can come up with his an ungodly amount of hard coding, is there another quick method?

You can use reflection to get the getters of those fields and generate code which reads out those getters.

The code generation can then be part of a build step.